# Using git hooks post commit to serve a subdirectory folder (dist/public) to a testing server

Tags: linux, git, apache, githooks

So I have a directory structure like so:

```
- Source
  - site a 
  - site b
  - site c
  - localhost(home directory for local test server)
    -  site a test
    -  site b test
    -  site c test
```

The way i currently have it set up is that the sites in the Source folder are the working versions. 
When i am happy to test a feature i have a git hook post-commit set up to serve them into the localhost folder under the corresponding site name.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
   git --work-tree=/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me/ --git-dir=/Users/kevin/Source/www.kevvin.me/.git checkout -f
```

So i commit the changes I have made and the local linux server reflects the changes. I also have a git hook set up on the production server that pulls in the latest changes on a push(When I have finished testing).

**The problem is** this only works for static sites/sites without a sub directory structure like a /dist/ folder within.

**I can't find a way to push my whole branch, while only serving my server with the /dist/ folder using git hooks**.

I have found a few close answers using git subtree but these all involve using a separate directory folder and linking it to the working one with subtree. **I need to use the git hooks to select an already present subfolder */dist/* and send that to the local server.**

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You might want to use `git archive --format=tar ... | tar -C <path> -x ...`.  (It's not clear to me whether you want to *strip* `dist/` from the extracted path names, but `--strip-components=1` will do that; see [the `tar` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).)  There are a bunch of sticky little details, though.  Only one of these is what goes in the `...` parts.

#### Long

> I need to use the git hooks to select an already present subfolder `dist/` and send that to the local server.

You *can* do that.  You just can't do that *easily* (well, how easy it is depends on your available tools).  Fortunately you've cross-tagged this with `linux` so we can assume you have Linux tools.

Let's look first at your existing post-receive hook and note some flaws:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```

(so far so good)

> ```
> unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
> ```

This line does nothing useful (but is harmless).  It's interesting, though: with the index file unset, what index will Git use?  The answer is of course the default index, `$GIT_DIR/index`.

I'll break the next line into parts:

> ```
> git --work-tree=/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me/ \
> ```

The `--work-tree` option here is important: the server repository is likely a bare repository.  This overrides the bare-ness and chooses a different work-tree.  The index then needs to match this work-tree, and generally will.

If the repository *isn't* bare, there are a number of possible problems, including using the main index to index this alternate work-tree.  It might be a lot wiser to point the index file elsewhere, or even use an added work-tree (`git worktree add`), although when I experimented, this played very poorly with receiving repositories.  (In particular modern Git lets you set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead`, but if you do so with an added work-tree, Git fails to update the added work-tree.)

> ```
> --git-dir=/Users/kevin/Source/www.kevvin.me/.git
> ```

Since this is a post-receive hook, it should already have `$GIT_DIR` set to the correct directory.  Overriding `$GIT_DIR` with `--git-dir` seems like a peculiar thing to do.  Moreover, the path here is generally a path that would be for a non-bare repository, so we're in the "unset `GIT_INDEX_FILE` seems suspect" territory.

> ```
> checkout -f
> ```

This will run `git checkout -f` with `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` set as directed by the two options.  What branch will `git checkout -f` check out?  Well, that's in [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html), which says, in part:

> You could omit <branch>, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the ***current branch***" ...

(emphasis mine).  So which branch is the *current* branch?  Well, that's the one set up in `$GIT_DIR` as the current branch.

Note that you will check out the current branch *regardless* of which branch(es) and/or tag(s) and/or note(s) were actually updated by `git push`.  So this particular post-receive script, while serviceable, is not very *good*.  We can definitely do better.

#### A better deployment script

First, we should read through the names updated by the `git push`:

```
while read old new ref; do
    ...
done
```

Inside the loop we can inspect `$old`, `$new`, and `$ref` to see:

- Which reference was successfully altered? (`$ref`)
- What hash ID did that reference name before the change? (`$old`)
- What hash ID does that reference name now? (`$new`)

We can also check to see if the reference was *created* (`$old` is all-zero) or *deleted* (`$new` is all-zero).  Presumably, though, you only want to deploy when one particular branch name, `refs/heads/name`, has been updated; and presumably that name exists and will never be deleted.  Hence, we can just check the name, which must exactly match `refs/heads/deployme` if the branch to be deployed is named `deployme`:

```
while read old new ref; do
    case $ref in
    refs/heads/deployme) deploy $new;;  # target branch updated: deploy it
    *) continue;;  # something else happened: ignore
    esac
done
```

So that's our loop to run; now we need to write the `deploy` function.

Note that if you want to deploy *different* branches into *different locations* for testing purposes, you can expand the loop and/or fancy-up the `deploy` function.  For now, we'll stick to a simple one.

#### The deployment function

Since what you want to do is extract the `dist/` sub-directory from the committed snapshot, let's start by writing our `deploy` function to archive just the `dist/` directory:

```
# called with one argument, which is the hash ID of the
# commit we are to deploy
deploy() {
    git archive --format=tar $1 dist/ | ...
}
```

The `git archive` command (which does not need any `--git-dir` or `--work-tree` arguments here) will write, as a tar archive, the contents of the `dist` directory stored in the commit identified by the hash ID in `$1`.  So `tar`, when we run it, will get only paths that start with `dist/`.  That means we don't have to fuss with restricting what we extract; we can just `-x` everything.

The `tar` command we will need is either:

```
tar -C /Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me/
```

or the same with `--strip-components=1` if you want to ditch the `dist/` part.  But there's a risk here: what if the *old* commit / contents of `/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me/` has a file named `junk` that is no longer in `dist/junk` in the *new* commit?  This `tar -C` command won't *remove* the `junk` file.

If that's what you want, we're done; but if not, we need some way to clean out any files we *don't* extract.  One nice method of doing this is to extract the files, not directly to `/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me/`, but rather to a temporary directory on the same file system.  We can then *rename* the `www.kevvin.me` directory out of the way and *rename* the new temporary directory into place, which minimizes the disruption time—the whole thing only takes as long as two renames—and then clean up the renamed-out-of-the-way `www.kevvin.me` directory.

Note that if you do this, you should account for the possibility that a second `git push` starts up a *new* deployment of a *new* replacement while the old one is still deploying or cleaning-up the deployment.  It's up to you to make this work properly (or just live with it and assume that it won't happen).  A pid-based lock system is not a bad idea here, to be really foolproof, but it's too complicated for me to write up here.

Last, there's a rather dirty/ugly method for deploying cleanly, which is to first remove everything and then extract the tar file.  I'll show that one first since it's the simplest of the methods, but it's also the worst one:

```
deploy() {
    local target=/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me

    rm -rf $target && mkdir $target
    git archive --format=tar $1 -- dist/ | tar -C $target -x --strip-components=1
}
```

Here's one that uses a temporary directory, without locking:

```
deploy() {
    local target=/Users/kevin/Source/local-host/www.kevvin.me
    local tmpdir=$(mktemp -d $(dirname $target)/.newXXXXXXXX)
    local olddir=$(mktemp -d $(dirname $target)/.oldXXXXXXXX)

    git archive --format=tar $1 -- dist/ | tar -C $tmpdir -x --strip-components=1
    mv $target $olddir && mv $tmpdir $target && rm -rf $olddir
}
```

There are, of course, any number of additional bits of tweaking you can do with this.  You could also write a tool to do the update in-place, reading the tar archive and comparing its contents to the existing contents of the existing tree.  If this process is slow, though, note that you will have some period during which the deployed tree will be a mix of old and new contents.  That's why the directory-swap trick is so nice.  Note that it assumes that `$(dirname $target)/.newXXXXXXXX` produces a path that's on the same mount point as the target, though.

Comment: I'm just here to praise the effort put into this answer. Deserves more recognition.